# Command Substitution - order of evaluation in Bash

Tags: bash

I was trying to run this seemingly simple script which should display the functionality of the -a flag of touch: `diff <(stat file.o) <(touch -a file.o; stat file.o)`. The output of this command is sporadic - obviously sometimes touch gets executed after everything else has been evaluated - but in an example as: `diff <(echo first) <(echo second; echo third)` - the order is kept. So why doesnt the first command work aswell?

Comment: In `diff <(echo first) <(echo second; echo third)`, there's no guarantee of ordering between when `echo first` and `echo second; echo third` happen relative to each other. The only ordering that really exists is the order of when `diff` _reads the output_ of the two subshells, which makes the timing between when the `echo`s first tried to run irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <( command-list ) syntax does the following:

1. Run command-list **asynchronously**
2. Store output of command-list in a temporary file
3. Replace itself on the command line with the path to that temporary file

See [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

The first point is likely what is tripping you up. There is no guarantee that your first process substitution will run before your second process substitution, therefore `touch -a` might be executed before either call to `stat`.

Your second example will always work as expected, because the output of each individual process substitution will be serialized. Even if `echo second` happens before `echo first`, they'll still be written to their respective temporary files and `echo third` will always happen after `echo second` so they will appear in the correct order in their file. The overall order of the two process substitutions doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Both commands happen at the same time.

That is to say, `touch -a file.o; stat file.o` from one process substitution and `stat file.o` from the other are happening concurrently.

So sometimes the `touch` happens before the process substitution that only has a `stat`; that means that *both* the `stat` commands see the effect of the `touch`, because (in that instance) the `touch` happened first.

As an (ugly, bad-practice) example, you can observe that it no longer happens when you add a delay:

```
diff <(stat file.o) <(sleep 1; touch -a file.o; stat file.o)
```